# Trying to pick a success message in Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm training on Selenium WebDrivers with JavaScript, I'm trying a simple walkthrough :

1. opening chrome and browsing to a specific web page
2. looking for the input field and entering an email address (user@email.com)
3. clicking on the button
4. then picking the success message, and displaying it into my console

Steps 1,2 and 3 are no problem, but when I'm trying to add step 4, I don't receive the success message anymore on the page, it looks like my "step 4" code is preventing "step 3" to be executed properly

Here is my code :

```
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var webdriver = require ('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;
   
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();


//Step 1

driver.get('https://library-app.firebaseapp.com/');


//Step 2

driver.findElement(By.css('input')).sendKeys('user@email.com');

//Step 3

driver.findElement(By.css('.btn')).click();

//I let 1 sec for the success message to be displayed before I can look for it

driver.sleep(1000);

//Step 4
driver.findElement(By.css('.alert-success')).getText().then(function(txt) {

    console.log("The alert success text is : " + txt);
});
```

If I'm removing step 4, everything is working fine, the success message is displayed, but if I add Step 4 in my code, I don't get it, and then, I get the following error message :

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"css selector","selector":".alert-success"}

I'm obviously missing something here, but can't figure out what. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

The error occurred because the element wasn't created in the dom since the code didn't wait for the `sleep` to finish.

`driver.sleep` is a async function that returns a `Promise`.
you need to use `.then()` or `await` so your code will execute after the sleep time is over.

```
driver.sleep(1000).then( () => {
  //Step 4
  driver.findElement(By.css('.alert-success')).getText().then(function(txt) {
    console.log("The alert success text is : " + txt);
});
```

})

Comment: Sure. if my answer helped you, please mark it so other users could use it.